# Confusion about angle brackets in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently learning TypeScript and running into some confusion for what angle brackets are used.

I know that you can use it e.g. for generic types, then the brackets would stand behind:

```
function myFn<T>(param: T): T {
  return param;
}
```

Also if you define a type for a generic type:

```
let identity = myFn<string>("hello world");
```

And that for arrays you can use it for one of two ways to define the types in an array:

```
let myArr: Array<number>;
```

For what cases would the brackets stand in front of a word? What other use cases are there to use angle brackets?

Comment: should the http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html be copied here? :)

Comment: Yes I read through the generic parts of that handbook. And apparently that is the part that I understood. But reading through the rest of the documentation there happen to be a lot of examples where it is not really clear to me what the angle brackets are used for. Especially when it comes first and not after.

Comment: @Aniket Saharwat thanks captain obvious. As I told you I AM reading through that handbook, but that doesn't necessarily means that you understand every part of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an alternative syntax for [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

```
let a = 1 as any;
// is equivalent to
let a = <any>1;
```

That's useful when you want the compiler to treat a value as specific type that's different to the one it has already been assigned or inferred for it.

Answer (score 63):

Let's break it down, shall we?

```
function myFn<T>(param: T): T {
  return param;
}
```

1. `function`: its Typescript keyword, denoting that you are declaring a function.
2. `myFn`: the name of the `function` in point 1.
3. `<T>`: This means that the function declare is gonna use a generic type: either in the arguments that it's gonna take in, or the return type. You, as a developer, will need to set it explicitly.
4. `(param:T)`: You have exactly one argument, by the name of `param`. At the same time, `param` is of type `T`, which you have set so in point 3.
5. `:T`: This denotes that the function which you declared in point 1 will have to return a value of type `T`.
6. `{ return param }`: returns the value of `param`. Note that this is allowed, because `param` is of type `T` and your function needs to return a type `T`. Let's consider another snippet:

This is not allowed:

```
function myFn<T>(param: T): T {
  return 0;
}
```

Reason being `0` is of type `number` and not type `T`.

Let's put it in pure English:

You are declaring a `function` called `myFn` which gonna take in an argument of type `T` and is going to return a value of type `T`.

That's it. Now, on the real usage:

```
let identity = myFn<string>("hello world");
```

The variable `identity` will be reference of a function that takes in an argument(remember params?) which is of type `string`. It will return the value of type `string` as well -- and according to the function declaration, it is going to return `"hello world"`.

You can read more on [Type Assertion of Typsecript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: nice explanation